# Riemann surfaces from a number theoretic point of view

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, riemann-surfaces

I need to learn the basic theory of Riemann surfaces and would like to pick a book which is most relevant to algebraic number theory. I have a good understanding of all underdraduate algebra and the basic theory of one complex variable. I do not have any prior exposure to algebraic geometry however. Can anyone recommend a book which would be a good match?

Many thanks!

Comment: You might have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88740/good-book-on-riemann-surfaces-and-galois-theory and maybe http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=GSM-37

Answer (score 2):

The basic theory of Riemannian surfaces can be found in many books, see for example the literature given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135047/perspectives-on-riemann-surfaces?rq=1). An important application to number theory is also the question on the spectrum of the Laplacian in Riemannian Geometry. This has a lot of number theory involved, see [Selberg's eigenvalue conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145637/best-record-toward-selbergs-eigenvalue-conjecture). 
For  literature, see also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68376/laplace-beltrami-operator-on-surfaces); also Peter Sarnak's article [Selberg's eigenvalue conjecture](http://www.ams.org/notices/199511/sarnak.pdf) gives a nice survey, with "pictures" of the Riemannian surfaces $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma(N)$ involved. These surfaces are central from many points of view, for example, in
the formulation of the (former) Shimura-Taniyama conjectures and the work of Andrew Wiles et al.